# iPhone:Programmatically find the count of videos and images from photo album?

Tags: iphone

I am developing app on iOS 4.3 SDK. I would like to know, how to find how many images and videos are there in Camera photo library album. Is it possible to programmatically find a way to know the count of videos and images there in photo album?

Please advise.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use ALAssetsLibrary

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html

A good example how to use it can be find at link 
http://iphonetuts.com/tag/alassetslibrary-tutorial/

```
27    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum
28                     usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
29                   failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
30                       NSLog(@"Failure");
31                   }];
```

replace "ALAssetsGroupAlbum" with "ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos"

Comment: Ok. I am doing this way..NSArray *types = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:
                          UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    
    NSUInteger countVal = [types count];
    NSString* msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Count: %d",countVal];
    UIAlertView *alert = [ [UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test" message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil ];
    
    [alert show];  But it is always count as "2", but i have many photos and videos in my device. Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: I have changed the answer, Note that it works for ios4.0 and greater