# Get the total number of images in the "Saved Photos" album of an iPhone using objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I want to get the count of the number of images in the "Saved Photos" album of an iOS device using objective c.

I would be grateful to the experts here if they could post a small snippet and help me understand how it work.

Comment: I'd love to answer this question, [but somebody else has already asked your question and somebody else already answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403771/iphoneprogrammatically-find-the-count-of-videos-and-images-from-photo-album).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using DirectoryEnumerator :**

```
NSDirectoryEnumerator *direnum = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:yourSavedPhotosPath];
int count = 0;
while(NSString *file = [direnum nextObject])
{
    if([[file pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"PNG"])
        count++;
}
NSLog(@"count :: %d",count);
```

**Using Predicate :**

```
NSArray *contents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:yourSavedPhotosPath error:nil];
NSArray *files = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF ENDSWITH '.PNG'",]];
int count = [files count];
```